# Why does text render so badly when positioned over a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have an `h1` and `a` positioned over a `canvas` element. It ends up looking like this:

[image]

(note the weird black boxes around the text)

If it's relevant, this text is part of an overlay that fades in/out on mouseover (handled with css `:hover`). The code is very simple and exactly what you'd expect, i think, but i'm happy to post if the answer isn't obvious.

Edit: Chrome-related? It actually looks fine on Safari

Any ideas?

Edit: relevant code (i think):

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <canvas class="preview-canvas">
  </canvas>
  <div class="rollover-overlay">
    <h1 class="game-title">NAME</h1>
    <a class="play-button">play</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

--

```
.col-sm-6 {
    position: relative;
}

.rollover-overlay {
    /* width and height set dynamically */
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 15;
    text-align: center;
    transition: background-color 300ms;
}

.game-title {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 300ms;
}

a.play-button {
    opacity: 0;
    background-color:transparent;
    transition: opacity 300ms, color 100ms, border-color 100ms;
}

.rollover-overlay:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.rollover-overlay:hover .game-title, 
.rollover-overlay:hover a.play-button {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

--

Comment: You have to use `<foreignObject>`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas

Comment: Looks like that's for drawing html onto a canvas. The 'snake' heading etc. is actually a separate element `absolute`ly `position`ed over the canvas element. Is `foreignObject` still relevant?

Comment: I'm sure the specs say that you shouldn't position html over a canvas because it's not part of the DOM's rendering flow. That's why you use the foreignObject so that the canvas is aware of the elements.

Comment: Yes, please post your code (only the relevant one, don't need to see the whole game if you can reproduce it on simpler one)

Comment: Thanks for your attention! I added the html and css. I don't actually think there's relevant js - all it's doing is running the game on the canvas (and resizing `div.rollover-overlay` to match the canvas -- relevant?)

Comment: @ThinkingMedia I was trying to avoid using `foreignObject` to keep as much of the layout out of the js as possible, I'll definitely use it if there's no reliable way not to. Thanks for your help!

Comment: D3 comes with a core set of features for manipulating the canvas, and it might end up saving you a lot of time. https://d3js.org/

Comment: @ThinkingMedia aren't you completely mixing HTMLCanvas and svg ? Why an svg foreignObject ? d3 may be usefull with canvas because it has a lot of calculations helper, but it was definitely made for svg, not canvas. Also, even svg is part of the DOM, and `<canvas>` too. CSS positioning should be fine...

Comment: @sam, unfortunately, this is still not enough to reproduce your issue, you're definitely omitting some part of the css (I guess there is some shadowings and some font used : https://jsfiddle.net/2s3xzxg5/

Comment: @Kaiido you're completely right. I have confused canvas and svg. I've only been working with svg so I just defaulted to that.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia it happens ;-) also, you can position html elements over svg.

Comment: @Kaiido I have finally created a fiddle reproducing the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/5coetjvm/. It seems like the game has to be going on in the background to get the poor rendering to take place. Weird.